# Multiple Criteria Evaluate Match Function Prohibitively Slow?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code successfully executes for small data sets:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Left()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Dim ws1, _
            ws2 As Worksheet, _
            wb As Workbook
        
            Set wb = ThisWorkbook
            Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Adj")
            Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Deleted")
    
        Dim a, _
            b, _
            i, _
            j, _
            k As Long
            
            a = 957
            b = 290150
    
        Dim Item1, _
            Item2, _
            Arr() As Variant
    
        With ws2
            For i = 2 To a
                .Cells(i, 6) = Left(.Cells(i, 1), 11)
                .Cells(i, 7) = Right(.Cells(i, 1), 4)
            Next i
        End With
            
        With ws1
            For j = 2 To b
                ReDim Preserve Arr(j - 1)
                Item1 = Chr(34) & .Cells(j, 7) & Chr(34)
                Item2 = Chr(34) & .Cells(j, 9) & Chr(34)
                On Error Resume Next
                    k = Evaluate("=MATCH(1,('Deleted'!F:F = " & Item1 & ")*('Deleted'!G:G = " & Item2 & "),0)")
                    If Err.Number = 13 Then
                        Arr(j - 1) = ""
                        Else: Arr(j - 1) = k
                    End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next j
            .Range(.Cells(2, 15), .Cells(b, 15)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr())
        End With
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

However, for large data sets - such as 290,150 rows - the macro spins its wheels. It's known that `Evaluate` is expensive to run and I have tried running for sample sizes of 30 (success) and 1,000 (unsuccessful) and debugged carefully. Obviously in-cell array formulation drag-and-drop is not a practical alternative. So, the problem reduces to resolving endless spinning for the given *multiple criteria match* function required.

How do I bypass this constraint?

Comment: did you mean to define ws1, a, b, i, j, & k as variant?

Comment: `Dim a, b, i, j, k, m As Long` - You actually declared `m` as Long only, the rest are considered Variant. You have to declare them as `Dim a As Long, b As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long`. Same goes for other variables that you did not declare its variable type (ws1, Item1 and Item2 should be String?)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: ws1 declared as Worksheet whilst a, b, i, j and k are Longs. Locals window indicates variables have been declared properly?

Comment: Objective: looping through the entire data set to find specified matches which change with each iteration.

Comment: Actually, after declaring as suggested by @RaymondWu, variables declaration changed. For example, { a, b, i, j, k } now read "Long" in Locals not "Variant/Long". Macro still spinning however.

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner - Sorry I should have mentioned this in my initial post, your issue is not due to this but just pointing out that the variables are not declared as what you expect it to be.

Comment: You already know the final size of arr() (it will be 1 to j-1) so there's no need to resize it by 1 every time through the loop - just size it before you enter the loop.

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams. Also stated Ranges instead of Columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach using a dictionary as a lookup:

```vb
Sub Left()

    Dim wsAdj As Worksheet, wsDel As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim lrDel As Long, lrAdj As Long, r As Long
    Dim dict, t, arr, arrG, arrI, arrRes, k
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsAdj = wb.Worksheets("Adj")
    Set wsDel = wb.Worksheets("Deleted")

    lrAdj = 290150
    lrDel = 957
    
    t = Timer
    
    'load a dictionary with lookup values constructed from wsDel ColA
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arr = wsDel.Range("A2:A" & lrDel).Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        k = Left(arr(r, 1), 11) & Chr(0) & Right(arr(r, 1), 4)
        dict(k) = r + 1 '+1 to adjust for starting at row 2
    Next r
    
    arrG = wsAdj.Range("G2:G" & lrAdj).Value    'get the match columns as arrays
    arrI = wsAdj.Range("I2:I" & lrAdj).Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrG, 1), 1 To 1)  'resize the "result" array
    
    'loop the values from wsAdj
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrG, 1)
        k = arrG(r, 1) & Chr(0) & arrI(r, 1) 'build the "key"
        If dict.exists(k) Then
            arrRes(r, 1) = dict(k) 'get the matched row
        End If
    Next r
    
    wsAdj.Cells(2, 15).Resize(UBound(arrRes, 1), 1).Value = arrRes 'put the array on the sheet

    Debug.Print "done", Timer - t ' <1 sec
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Stating Ranges instead of Columns and removing ReDim on loop helped.